# for loop test case in C

Tags: c, loops

Recently I discovered that I'm not nearly as good at C as I thought myself to be, and while doing some quick reviewing I stumbled upon this little programme from http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr11/cos217/lectures/02CExamples.pdf>here

On page 7, it has

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int c, i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        c = getchar();
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the question is why use `i=0; i<10` in the loop instead of `i=1; i<=10`.

I always thought these two forms are identical as long as the value of i is not being used in later codes but apparently I'm missing something. This is from Princeton and I can't imagine them making mistakes like this so I tested a few simple cases but they seem to be identical. Now I just feel really bad not able to answer such a simple question. I googled and searched within the site but didn't find anything. Please help. Thanks!

EDIT: thanks everyone for answering now at least i know there is not any significant difference. I actually have some programming experiences but since I mostly taught myself I thought I was missing something obvious. thanks again.

Comment: Why do you think `i=1; i<=10` is correct and `i=0; i<10` is a "mistake" ?

Comment: i was actually under the impression that i=1; i<=10 is not as good as the other way in this example for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context given they are the same. If you were using to access an array in C (which is 0 based...) - I'm assuming the answer is basically "to be consistent"

Answer (score 2):

> why use `i=0; i<10` in the loop instead of `i=1; i<=10`.

It will make no difference in your program. However, if you are accessing an array, you will need to use the first form. The second form will cause undefined behavior.

```
int a[10];
int i;
for ( i = 1; i <= 10; ++i )
{
   a[i] = i*2;   // Problem when i == 10.
}
```

It's better to use the first form to stay consistent in your program.

Comment: @R Sahu There is no problem with arrays when the second form of loop is used. Why may not you write for example a[i-1] = i * 2? So it is not a problem of the loop. It is a problem of the programmer who uses incorrect indices.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Any modern compiler will understand that both forms mean that the loop needs to execute ten times and they'll find the most efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the generated assembly code for both the code snippets and the compiler has treated both the snippets similarly.So there is no difference

```
void f1 () 
{
    int c, i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        c = getchar();
        putchar(c);
    }
}   
f1():
    pushq   %rbx
    movl    $10, %ebx
.L2:
    movq    stdin(%rip), %rdi
    call    _IO_getc
    movq    stdout(%rip), %rsi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    _IO_putc
    subl    $1, %ebx
    jne .L2
    popq    %rbx
    ret

void f2() 
{
    int c, i;
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++){
        c = getchar();
        putchar(c);
    }
}   
f2():
    pushq   %rbx
    movl    $10, %ebx
.L7:
    movq    stdin(%rip), %rdi
    call    _IO_getc
    movq    stdout(%rip), %rsi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    _IO_putc
    subl    $1, %ebx
    jne .L7
    popq    %rbx
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

An essential difference exists if to replace the magic constant 10 with some integer variable that somehow is initialized before the loop.
So consider the following two loops.

```
int n = SOME_VALUE;

for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    /* ... */
}
```

and

```
int n = SOME_VALUE;

for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Now because in general case `n` can be assigned any value then the second loop is not equivalent to the first loop.:) The second loop is unsafe and can be infinite. Consider the case when `n` is set to `INT_MAX`. In this case when `i` will achieve this value `INT_MAX` condition `i <= n` will be true. As result `i` will be incremented and you can get that `i` will be equal to `INT_MIN`.
Because `INT_MIN <= INT_MAX` the loop will iterate anew.:)

So how to write in general case the second loop correctly? For example you could split it into loop with condition

```
for ( i = 1; i < n; i++ )
{
    /* ... */
}
```

and then repeat the body of the loop after the loop itself with i equal to n. So you will get

```
for ( i = 1; i < n; i++ )
{
    /* body of the loop */
}

/* body of the loop as separate code snippet */
```

The other way to write this loop correctly without splitting it is the following

```
for ( i = 1, j = 0; i <= n && j != n; j = i++ )
{
    /* body of the loop */
}
```

Usually programmers think that `n` never can be equal to `INT_MAX` the same way as they did not think that there will be 2000 year.:)